# Ошибка при создании базы c#

Tags: c#, sql, azure

Выполняю такой запрос:

```
Db.Query($"CREATE DATABASE MyDataBase");
```

База создаеться, но выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
Время ожидания выполнения истекло. Время ожидания истекло до завершения операции, или сервер не отвечает.
CREATE DATABASE operation failed. Internal service error
```

сервер - SQL SERVER Azure.
строка подключения

```
$"Server=tcp:servername;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=11000"
```

пробовал без `Initial Catalog=master;` точно также.
Использую библиотеку Dapper

Comment: попробуйте Db.Query($"CREATE DATABASE DataBase;");

Comment: Добавьте код соединения

Comment: @AzizUmarov добавил

Comment: `DATABASE` - ключевое слово. Вы действительно создаёте БД с таким именем?

Comment: Вообще, о какой БД речь? Sql Server? Так-то по строке соединения можно сообразить, но не заставляйте других гадать.

Comment: `Db.Query` - что это? Из какой библиотеки класс и метод? Или ваше самописное? Повторяю ещё раз: не заставляйте других гадать. Уточняйте **всю** необходимую информацию в вопросе. Ставьте метки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Все описал в вопросе

Comment: Рекомендую сначала проверить с помощью любого mssql-клиента, что соединение с sql-сервером устанавливается

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Ну база создаётся ж.